# Laravel 55 - Passport & Vue - auth/login/logout

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, laravel-5.5

With a laravel 55, I have installed the auth system, then passport. My Vue components can request to api protected with api:auth middleware (using CreateFreshApiToken in Kernel.php).

So, when using axios, if a make a request to /api/myroute it will respond correctly via the api.php setup

And if I make a request to /myroute  the app will respond via web.php setup

Now when it comes to SPA App, one would like to be able to refresh the app token once the session is timed out.

If I use the standard login page to login to app, and if I kill the web session in the database, axios requests to /api/myroute are still valid.

To simulate the end of session (401 response), I need to make an axios request to /logout (via web.php).

But this is were I get lost.I would like to simulate forced logout or end of session for api requests.

How can we mix passport auth for api and standard auth routes so that we don't have to remake the full story (login, logout, register, revoke, refresh) for a SPA app please ?

Comment: With the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware, Laravel should automatically handle the tokens for you. You appear to be saying that there is another mechanism in your app that defines whether a session is active. If that's the case you can simply perform the relevant check in middleware.

Comment: Well, i would be pleased to do so, but how do you (not) modify vendor files ?
Each of my axios request has this via bootstrap.js :
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
if (token) 
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;

if I wan to remotely (like an admin) disconnect a user, I can block the web part but the token continues to live and so, each xhttprequest via axios let the user interact with the laravel app

Answer (score 0):

You can place the middleware directly on your `api` route, so:

`php artisan make:middleware UserLoggedIn`

Then in that middleware you would do something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(!$user->hasActiveSession()){
        // User has been logged out, return a 401
        return response('Not Authorized', 401);
    }


    return $next($request);
}
```

Obviously a `hasActiveSession` method would need to be placed in your `User` model for whatever check you need to do to make sure the user session is active.

Then in `Kernel.php` add the following to `$routeMiddleware`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [ 
    // ...other route middleware...
    'user.loggedIn' => UserLoggedIn::class
];
```

Then on your api route you can add the middleware:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api','user.loggedIn'])->get('/myRoute','MyController@myMethod')
```

Comment: I guess you're correct. so will try it. I understand the concept of using my own middleware. but shouldn't this the role of a "guard" and why isn't this directly onboard by CreateFreshApiToken ?

In my use case, at the end, what is dangerous is that you can't "blacklist" the larval_token cookie generated once loggedin.

to go further, how would you create a controller for admins only where you could disconnect "connected users" ?

Comment: It looks like these tokens only exist on the user end, so you will need some mechanism to trigger the logout method. I think the cleanest way to do that would be to [broadcast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting) a message that calls your logout method when disconnected by admin (Laravel has inbuilt support for [pusher](https://pusher.com) which is pretty simple to implement), that way your user will know that they have been logged out instantly.